# Progress bar while loading file attachment

Tags: vb.net, excel, progress-bar

I'm having a problem about loading progress bar while attaching file. I want progress bar works until it finish scanning the attachment file. The problem is when I attach the file and start to scan, maybe 3-5 seconds working of my progress bar, I want that progress bar will continue until the file is finish to scan.

Here's my code for opendialog:

```
 Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        strm = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        filename = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        TextBox1.Text = filename
        If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then
            strm.Close()
        End If
 End Sub
```

Code for browse button:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select a File"
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:temp"
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
 End Sub
```

Code for generating attachment file:

```
 Private Sub cmdGenerate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdIntralinks.Click
    conn.Open()
       Timer1.Enabled = True 
       Timer1.Interval = 50 
       ProgressBar1.Value = 0
conn.close()
```

Code for timer1_tick:

```
   Private Sub Timer1_Tick_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Static TikTok As Integer
        TikTok = TikTok + 1
        ProgressBar1.Value = TikTok
        If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
            Timer1.Enabled = False
            TikTok = 0
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You need to run the 'guts' of the program on a differant stream from the user interface. Research the `BackgroundWorker` class.

Comment: It's not working.. Why ohh why..

Answer (score 0):

See if it works:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static TikTok As Integer
    TikTok = TikTok + 1
    ProgressBar1.Value = TikTok
    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        TikTok = 0
    End If
   Application.DoEvents()
End Sub
```

btw, did you already put a breakpoint into that if clause to see if the progressbar.maximum is reaching its maximum before the expected?
cya